# Purpose of "Target machine" field in Visual studio -> Linker-> Advanced Options->Target Machine

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, porting

I'm porting a 32-bit C++ app to 64-bit (using VS2008).
I'm not sure what does this field mean in the VS2008 ::

```
Visual studio ->Configuration Properties-> Linker-> Advanced Options->Target Machine.
```

By default it's value is set to "**Not set**". 
**Is it compulsory to change it's value to "MACHINEx64" if I want my application to be ported to 64-bit executable.**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a very important option.  It sets the [IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Machine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms680313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) field in the executable file.  The very first field of the EXE or DLL header.

Windows check this when it loads an EXE and knows whether it needs to create a 32-bit or a 64-bit process from that field.  The only reason it is a the Linker + Advanced property page is because you don't normally change it.  The setting is pre-selected by the project configuration you created.  If you get "Not Set" then you are basically doing it wrong, hard to guess what you are doing.

Assuming you have a properly configured project that builds a working 32-bit build for your program, you create the 64-bit build with Build + Configuration Manager.  In the "Active solution platform" combobox at the upper right, select `<New...>`.  Pick "x64" in the dialog.  Hopefully the other defaults (Copy settings from = Win32, Create new project platforms ticked) are correct for yours.  Go back to the Linker + Advanced property page and the setting should have changed to MachineX64.

Comment: You are mixing compiler settings and linker settings. The linker should determine the architecture from the already generated object file. See MSDN on this flag.

Comment: I'm not, just talking about linker settings here.  Obviously the compiler matters a great deal when choosing between x86 and x64 but it gets much murkier for mobile processors.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Excellent explanation. :) Yes, you are right. When in 32-bit mode I see the default value for "Target machine" field is "MACHINEx86". But when I select 64-bit mode, the default value is "Not set". That is the reason when I'm running my 64-bit ported exe , it's running as 32-bit process. But I'm not sure what is going wrong that it's not getting set as "MACHINEx64" !! I did change  2 things :: In COnfiguration manager of this project I changed to x64 and also in top of VS there is an option to change from Win32 to x64, as per your explanation

Comment: Trying to figure out what has gone wrong. If you can provide any other inputs?

Comment: I can't guess what went wrong, you didn't describe what you did at all.  Why don't you delete the configuration and add it back using the steps I described.  From the same combobox, select Edit, select the x64 and click Remove.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thank you. Yes, I did delete "x64" and recreate as you explained and it worked. But the problem is that only for "debug" mode  the "x64MACHINE" value is present in "Target Machine" field. When I change to "Release" mode I can again see only "Not Set" as the value in this field.

Answer (score 2):

This option relates to the linker option /MACHINE and is a hint for the linker for what target architecture to link the object code if he (the linker) cannot determine this from the object file. As MSDN states you usually have not to specify this. So no you don't need to explicitly specify this flag when porting your code.