# Linker -> Advanced -> Target Machine

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, linker

This question was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572981/purpose-of-target-machine-field-in-visual-studio-linker-advanced-options), but there is no answer yet, so i will try to recap it.

[image]

So here is the Problem, i realized on one project, tat the Platform was choosen to be "Win32" but under **"Linker > Advanced -> TargetMachine"** i had **"MachineX64(/MACHINE.x64)**

So what is the purpose oft his option? In which case is this option usefull and what happens when i choosen Plattform:Win32 and change the TargetMachine Setting to X64?

Comment: The other question already answers this, it sets the machine field in the PE header: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms680313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: So fix your problem and set it correctly.  You don't need our help with that.  The purpose is to set a field in the header, many linker options are dedicated to that.  And no, it isn't automatic since a DLL doesn't have to contain code.  Resource-only DLLs and .NET assemblies are standard examples.  You can set the option wrong on those DLLs but you'll just give the client app a hard time to load the DLL, having to fall back to LoadLibraryEx().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won´t work. The linker gets 32bit file from the compiler
but is told to process/make 64bit stuff => Error. Just try it.

The main reason is that in some cases the linker can´t determine
the correct setting from the compiler output.

Comment: it works actually, i have no error, i don't know if its now built to x64 or x86 target